# Refer a String for Creating Class Dynamically

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, declaration

I want to use a string as class member name. the way I thought (but it doesn't work) is in the below.

```
class Constant():
    def add_Constant(self, name, value): self.locals()[name] = value  # <- this doesn't work!
# class

CONST = Constant()
CONST.add_Constant(name='EULER', value=2.718)
print(CONST.EULER)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I linked some duplicates that explain the standard tools for addressing your question in Python. But - why not [just use a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)? Or an [enum with custom values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet), depending on the actual *problem you are trying to solve* with the `Constant` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class Constant():
    def add_Constant(self, name, value):
        setattr(self, name, value) # <- this does work!

CONST = Constant()
CONST.add_Constant(name='EULER', value=2.718)
print(CONST.EULER)
```

This outputs:

```py
2.718
```

Comment: isʞuɐɥʇ ʎǝɥ 
hey thanks!